# Chrome extension popup stopped working when I started using folders

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

This might be a simple issue, but I'm new to chrome extension development, so thank you guys for your help!

I used an online tutorial and made a chrome extension, then I wanted to make things more organized and started creating folders but then it seems the extension isn't working any more! the popup window isn't showing any more! All I did was creating a folder called 'media' and then another folder in it called 'icons' and dropped my 3 icons in there. then in manifest file:

```
...
"icons": {
    "128": "media/icons/icon128.png",
    "48": "media/icons/icon48.png",
    "16": "media/icons/icon16.png"
},
"page_action": {
    "default_icon": "media/icons/icon16.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "PageFontStyle"
},
...
```

Why did it break when I put the icons in a folder? What did I do wrong? I want to be able to organize things

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

Ah found the issue, apparently reloading the extension wasn't enough and I needed to restart the chrome itself! lol it didn't start working straight after I restarted chrome, probably took half a minute or so for some reason